# How to use slotcar plugin for my own robot?

Tags: ros, ros2, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have read about the RMF in ROS2, but I want to use slotcar plugin for my own robot in ROS1 to integrate it into the RMF.
Beside adding [this plugin](https://osrf.github.io/ros2multirobotbook/simulation.html#:%7E:text=%3Cplugin%20name,stop_radius%3E%0A%3C/plugin%3E) to my urdf robot file and change the parameters, should I do anything else for this to work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392134/how-to-use-slotcar-plugin-for-my-own-robot?/) by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2021-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Kevin1719

To use the plugin you will need to compile it as a library then added to your model urdf/sdf:
Refer to this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_model&cat=write_plugin) that shows you how to.

To add it to library path:

```
export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=$HOME/gazebo_plugin_tutorial/build:$GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH
```

The source code for the slotcar plugin can be found in this [repo](https://github.com/AI806/RMF-AMRs/blob/326fc85e70bc37e66b3ce87c93e1381038c7dc79/rmf/rmf_traffic_editor/building_sim_plugins/building_ignition_plugins/src/slotcar.cpp)

```
class IGNITION_GAZEBO_VISIBLE SlotcarPlugin
  : public System,
  public ISystemConfigure,
  public ISystemPreUpdate
```

As per the tutorial in your link to use:

```
<plugin name="slotcar" filename="libslotcar.so">
  <nominal_drive_speed>0.5</nominal_drive_speed>
  <nominal_drive_acceleration>0.25</nominal_drive_acceleration>
  <max_drive_acceleration>0.75</max_drive_acceleration>
  <nominal_turn_speed>0.6</nominal_turn_speed>
  <nominal_turn_acceleration>1.5</nominal_turn_acceleration>
  <max_turn_acceleration>2.0</max_turn_acceleration>
  <tire_radius>0.1</tire_radius>
  <base_width>0.3206</base_width>
  <stop_distance>0.75</stop_distance>
  <stop_radius>0.75</stop_radius>
</plugin>
```

To use with ROS, then refer to this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) how to add Gazebo Plugins.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on 2021-12-05**:
Thanks @osilva for a comprehensive answer, I will follow your instructions and reply the outcome as soon as possible. By the way, I'm wondering how slotcar simulates robot models in Gazebo, when I launch the clinic demo from [this](https://github.com/open-rmf/rmf_demos/blob/main/rmf_demos_gz/launch/clinic.launch.xml), I can see it publishes messages to /robot_state topic after running rqt_graph command, but Gazebo doesn't subscribe to that topic, and the robots still move normally in Gazebo simulation. Can you explain the mechanism under the hood, please?

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-05**:
I think the best way is to study the source code for the [plugin link](https://github.com/AI806/RMF-AMRs/blob/326fc85e70bc37e66b3ce87c93e1381038c7dc79/rmf/rmf_traffic_editor/building_sim_plugins/building_ignition_plugins/src/slotcar.cpp)

```
void SlotcarPlugin::send_control_signals(EntityComponentManager& ecm,
  const std::pair<double, double>& velocities,
  const std::unordered_set<Entity> payloads,
  const double dt)
{
  auto lin_vel_cmd =
    ecm.Component<components::LinearVelocityCmd>(_entity);
  auto ang_vel_cmd =
    ecm.Component<components::AngularVelocityCmd>(_entity);

  double v_robot = lin_vel_cmd->Data()[0];
  double w_robot = ang_vel_cmd->Data()[2];
  std::array<double, 2> target_vels;
  target_vels = dataPtr->calculate_model_control_signals({v_robot, w_robot},
      velocities, dt);
```

For example the function above sends control signals of linear and angular velocities.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-05**:
The plugin is another gazebo objects that interacts with Gazebo's physics engine, so if the robot moves for example, the engine *knows* that the robot is in motion, those physical properties can be read by the plugin in simulation. Hope that makes a little more clear.

**Comment by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on 2021-12-06**:
@osilva Yes, that makes sense, I will dig into the code to see if there is anything related. Thanks a lot.